# Returning values from functions in structures in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, function, data-structures, procedure

I hope the title of the post isn't too much of a mess. I'm reviewing some course material from last week, and there is just one thing I don't understand in regard to this particular structure and the add and subtract functions in it:

```
  Structure ComNum
    Dim Re As Double
    Dim Im As Double
    Function add(ByVal br As ComNum) As ComNum
        add.Re = br.Re + Re
        add.Im = br.Im + Im
    End Function
    Function subt(ByVal br As ComNum) As ComNum
        subt.Re = br.Re - Re
        subt.Im = br.Im - Im
    End Function
End Structure

Sub Main()
    Dim a, b, c As ComNum

    a.Re = 2
    a.Im = 3
    b.Re = 4
    b.Im = 5

    c = a.add(b).add(b).subt(b)

    Console.WriteLine("The second number added twice and subtracted once from the first number gives {0}+{1}i", c.Re, c.Im)

End Sub
```

Now, the way I understand functions is that once anything is returned from it, execution of the function stops at that exact line where the value is returned and nothing after it gets executed. According to that, it should add the real part and exit the function.

I know I'm missing a key thing here and I'd appreciate it if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: Pretty unclear what you are stuck on.  Nothing is exiting a function early.  This looks almost like VB6 syntax.  I'm "guessing"  you want this to be a void, not a function, `Re += br.Re`, etc. Don't know.

Comment: As an aside, I'd caution against using mutable structures.  They tend to be *very* difficult to reason about.  Copies will be made at times you don't necessarily expect.

Comment: @Craig I shall keep that in mind going forward, thank you. But this was a specific exercise in school so it had to be the way it is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have this setup those functions are creating a new, empty ComNum structure each time you call them (named either add or subt based on the function name).  Unless you manually return them early it will just default to returning the function named structure.

```
    Function add(ByVal br As ComNum) As ComNum
        add.Re = br.Re + Re
        add.Im = br.Im + Im
    End Function
```

Is basically doing the equivalent of:

```
    Dim add As New ComNum
    add.Re = br.Re + Re
    add.Im = br.Im + Im
    Return add
```

Though like Lars pointed out I'm not sure why you'd want this to be a function vs a sub.  Using it the way you have it setup now requires you to do something like this to get the add/subtract values because you need to capture the returned ComNum object.

```
    Dim a As New ComNum With {.Im = 1, .Re = 1}
    'Im = 6, Re = 6
    a = a.add(New ComNum With {.Im = 5, .Re = 5})
```

Doing something like this makes more sense to me.

```
Structure ComNum
    Dim Re As Double
    Dim Im As Double
    Sub add(ByVal br As ComNum)
        Re += br.Re
        Im += br.Im
    End Sub
    Sub subt(ByVal br As ComNum)
        Re -= br.Re
        Im -= br.Im
    End Sub
End Structure
```

Then you could just call it this way to update the struct without having to capture the returned values.

```
a.add(New ComNum With {.Im = 5, .Re = 5})
```

Edit:  Knowing more now how the exercise is supposed to be performed I'd suggest something like this for the struct:

```
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("Re: {0}  Im: {1}", Re, Im)
    End Function
```

Then you could call the .ToString() method like this.  Though, just a thought.

```
    Console.WriteLine("The second number added twice and subtracted once from the first number gives {0}", c.ToString())
```

Comment: I managed to figure out how everything works on my own after fiddling with the code, but you were a big help by pointing me in the right direction. Thank you :)
As for why it was done the way it was, like I said in my edit of the opening post, it was an exercise in structures, functions and invocation chaining. The point was to define those operations in the structure without it altering the already input numbers for flexibility.

Comment: Glad I could help, how you described the exercise makes sense in that instance.  In a real-world application I'd probably use a list of that structure to calculate the addition/subtraction.  But homework/learning applications have pretty rigid structures so it works.  I've added an edit for possibly overriding the .ToString() method so you could call c.ToString() vs formatting the output manually every time.